# Kotlin named parameter syntax for closure/lambda

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I created the following function:

```
public fun storeImage(image: BufferedImage, toPath: String, 
    onCompletion: (contentURL: URL) -> Unit)
{
    val file = File(this.storageDirectory, toPath)
    log.debug("storing image: ${file.absolutePath}")
    val extension = toPath.extensionOrNull()
    if (!file.exists())
    {
        file.parentFile.mkdirs()
        file.createNewFile()
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, extension!!, FileOutputStream(file.absolutePath))
    onCompletion(URL(contentBaseUrl, toPath))
}
```

I can see that I can call it like this:

```
contentManager.storeImage(image, "1234/Foobar.jpg", onCompletion = {
    println("$it")
})
```

Or I can use trailing closure syntax:

```
contentManager.storeImage(image, "1234/Foobar.jpg") {
    println("$it")
}
```

But how do I call the store image method and call the onCompletion function using named parameters?

**Edit/Example:**

I would like to call the `storeImage` method using a syntax similar to:

```
contentManager.storeImage(image, "1234/Foobar.jpg", 
    onCompletion = (bar: URL) : Unit -> {
       //do something with bar
    }
```

I could not find the correct syntax in the docs for the above kind of thing.

Comment: To be clear, with "named parameters" you mean explicitly assigning your `contentURL` param? Because with the `onCompletion = ...` thing you're *already* using named parameters.

Comment: Yes, that what I mean. It is a very simple (but poorly worded, will try to fix) question.

Comment: Interesting corner case there. You're not allowed to, the compiler says "Named parameters are not allowed for function types". I've left a message for the kotlin people and let's see if we can get an answer as to why that's not possible.

Comment: Ah that's interesting. If I drop onCompletion = can i refer to the function parameter as 'contentURL' instead of 'it' ?

Comment: I think you're confusing two things: *declaration* of `onCompletion` (in the `storeImage` fun) can have named params ["for documentation"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types). In the *definition* of `onCompletion` you'd still need to use the closure syntax: `onCompletion = { contentURL -> /* do stuff */ }`. On the *call site*, you're not allowed to name the param: `onCompletion(URL(...))`.

Comment: What about a function with two or more parameters? How do we refer to them?

Comment: By name: `onCompletion = { name: String, contentURL: URL -> ... }`, call: `onCompletion("yes!", URL(...))`

Comment: I'm sorry. I worded my question very badly. I think the edit/example makes it more clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the regular syntax for giving names to lambda parameters. This works regardless of whether you're using a named argument to pass the lambda to the function.

```
contentManager.storeImage(image, "1234/Foobar.jpg", 
    onCompletion = { bar ->
       //do something with bar
    })
```

Comment: I added an IntelliJ feature suggestion, for consideration: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150085